# printf escape %q string vs variable

Tags: bash, printf

I would like to escape path with white space which works fine when I use it directly like this:

```
$ printf '%q' "/path/to/first dir/dir/"
/path/to/first\ dir/dir/
```

When I use a variable instead of string though the return is a string with no white space whatsoever:

```
$ testpath="/path/to/first dir/dir/" && printf '%q' $testpath
/path/to/firstdir/dir/
```

Is there any way to escape white space in a path with printf and a variable. Or any other simple solution without using awk/sed/regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote the variable

```
testpath="/path/to/first dir/dir/" && printf '%q' "$testpath"
```

Comment: I could swear I tested this. But it seems like I didn't, because quoting works.

Answer (score 3):

```
testpath="/path/to/first dir/dir/"
printf '%q' "$testpath"
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words